# AngularJs - Open url in new tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application with a public page and an admin page. I would like open the admin page in a new tab after login.
I've tried this, after the login was successful, but to no effect. The public page (where the login is) is just being reloaded:

```
var url = $state.href('/admin/overview');
$window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Any tips would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle and post the link here?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I cannot reproduce accurately the code in a fiddle. It's too complex.

Comment: Is "/admin/overview" a route name? because according to the docs you cannot use that method with URIs (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state). That might be part of the problem

Comment: Yes, it is a route name. That may be the cause of the problem. But I was unable to find an example with routes, so I just tried it.

Comment: The link I posted before shows several examples with route names, it's basically the only way to work with this method ($state.href that is)

Comment: Working exmaple : https://jsfiddle.net/aniket_kulkarni/wdzjcgeL/

Answer (score 37):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/sau2gocp/), you have to inject `$window` before you can use it:

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.redirectToGoogle = function () {
        $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy"> 
    <a ng-href="" ng-click="redirectToGoogle()">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works nicely when using an external URL (like the one you provided) but It does not work when trying to use router-ui states (or urls).

Answer (score 16):

Here's another working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16772/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<a ng-href="{{url}}" target="_blank">Visit jsfiddle</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.url ='http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16771/';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple method to open link in new tab,

```
 <a href="{{details.website}}" ng-click="openNewTab(details.website)"> 
    {{details.website}}
 </a>
     $scope.openNewTab = function (url) 
    {
      $window.open(url, '_blank');
     };
```

Before using it you should inject `$window` in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a directive to do this for you.

```js
directives.redirect = function ($location, $window, $rootScope) {
    return {

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on("click", function () {
                if (!attrs.newwindow || attrs.newwindow == false) {
                    $location.path(attrs.redirect);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
                else {
                    var baseUrl = $location.$$absUrl.toString().substring(0, decodeURIComponent($location.$$absUrl).toString().indexOf($location.$$path.toString(), $location.$$absUrl.toString().indexOf("#")) + 1) + attrs.redirect;
                    $window.open(baseUrl);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And in HTML, you can use the following to open in a new tab:

```
<a redirect="/admin/overview" newwindow="true">Open in new tab</a>
```

Comment: Here is working exmaple: https://jsfiddle.net/aniket_kulkarni/wdzjcgeL/

Comment: Your solution is putting the # in the _blank url. use this $location.$$absUrl.split('#')[0] + attrs.redirect;

Answer (score -1):

I used this and it works (angular4+):

`<button mat-menu-item>
    <a href="/faq/" target="_blank" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
        <mat-icon>help</mat-icon>FAQ
    </a>
</button>`

I had to restore color to default and override browser's colors. This still gives me the ripple effect and everything with zero javascript code.