# Open Link in Angular based on data from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have user GPS location, these are not fixed, and from frontend i have to open these as google map link.

```
<a href="#" ng-click='window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/place/{{data.usergps}}", "_system", "location=yes"); return false;'>Open Map</a>
```

the above give error of Syntax Error: Token 'false', but if i use same with onClick then it will work fine.

another method is to open using a function from controller,

```
$scope.openMap = function () {
      $scope.data.usermapLink="https://www.google.com/maps/place/33.719910,73.058354"
        $window.open($scope.data.usermapLink);
    };
```

View:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openMap()">Open Map</a>
```

But problem with this method is that it will open window and my view will be cleared at background, like view data will be cleared, when user press back button.

My Main objective is to open the link based on GPS coordinates from $scope.

Please Advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do like :

```
 ng-click = "openLink()"
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
 $scope.openLink = function(){
     $http.get("your.link.html");
 }
```

And also don't forget to inject `$http` in your controller.

Comment: Yes added, in view `<a href="#" ng-click="openMap()">Open Map</a>` but  no result.

Comment: @NisarAfridi Make it a `div` and not `href`

Comment: `div` ?? but then it wont be a link.

Comment: @NisarAfridi Ok if you need a link, then wrap that `href` in a `div` and on that div call the `ng-click`

Comment: `<td><div><a href="#" ng-click="openMap()">Open Map</a></div></td>` not working, it just reload view. `$http.get($scope.data.usermapLink);` in funciton.

Comment: Not like that, like this: `<td><div class= "something" ng-click="openMap()"><a href="#" >Open Map</a></div></td>`

Comment: Tried but still going back to #(view). but solved the issue using `window.open` i was doing a small mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I was not adding `ng-href`

View: `<a ng-href="" ng-click="openMap()">Open Map</a>`
Controller:

```
$scope.openMap = function () {
        $window.open($scope.data.usermapLink, '_system', 'location = yes');
    };
```

this will open map link in google map application.

Source: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/32198740/6915298][1]

Thanks